# [JavaScript]Why for progress bar addeventlistener is not working?

Tags: javascript, html, css

With the help od basic javascript I am trying to make a custom video player, though all of the controls are working fine, progress bar is getting updated according to time-update event, but when Iam trying to add the functionality that when the user clicks on progress bar the video currentTime should go to that time and progress bar should show the progress accordingly but when I am trying to addeventlistener for click event on progress bar it's not working  , I am simply using all bootstrap version 4 classes , and some basic CSS the code is as below ,why the addeventlistener is not working please see in the comments, I've marked the scrub(name of the function) function which is not called at all with the help of comments, I don't know why please help me on this.....if anyone knows how to add the functionality that I described above without changing the HTML

```js
let videoelement = document.querySelector('.videos')
let pausebutton = document.querySelector('.fas');
let skipbutton = document.querySelector('.forward');
let backbutton = document.querySelector('.backward');
let speed = document.querySelector('#playbackspeed');
let vol = document.querySelector('#volume');
let controls = document.querySelector('.controlplayer')
let progress = document.querySelector('.progress-bar')
vol.addEventListener('change', setvol)
vol.addEventListener('mousedown', setvol)
function setvol(e) {
    videoelement.volume = vol.value;
}
speed.addEventListener('change', rate)
speed.addEventListener('mousedown', rate)
function rate(e) {
    //  console.dir(speed);
    videoelement.playbackRate = speed.value;
}
pausebutton.addEventListener('click', playing)
videoelement.addEventListener('mouseenter', function () {
    controls.style.display = 'block';
})
videoelement.addEventListener('click', playing)
videoelement.addEventListener('play', updatebutton)
videoelement.addEventListener('pause', updatebutton)
videoelement.addEventListener('timeupdate', handleprogress)
function updatebutton() {
    if (videoelement.paused) {
        pausebutton.classList.remove('fa-pause')
        pausebutton.classList.add('fa-play')
    }
    else {
        pausebutton.classList.remove('fa-play')
        pausebutton.classList.add('fa-pause')
    }
}
function playing(e) {
    console.dir(videoelement)
    if (videoelement.paused) {
        // console.log("pause hai ")
        videoelement.play();
        playing
        videoelement.controls = null;
        videoelement.firstChild.nodeValue = 'Play';
        pausebutton.classList.remove('fa-play')
        pausebutton.classList.add('fa-pause')
    } else {
        //console.log("play ho gya")
        videoelement.pause();
        videoelement.firstChild.nodeValue = 'Pause';
        pausebutton.classList.remove('fa-pause')
        pausebutton.classList.add('fa-play')
    }
    //  this.preventDefault();
}
skipbutton.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    let t = videoelement.currentTime;
    if ((t + 25) < videoelement.duration)
        videoelement.currentTime = t + 25;
    else
        videoelement.currentTime = videoelement.duration;
})
backbutton.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    let t = videoelement.currentTime;
    if ((t - 10) >= 0)
        videoelement.currentTime = t - 10;
    else
        videoelement.currentTime = 0;
})
function handleprogress() {
    let percent = (videoelement.currentTime / videoelement.duration) * 100;
    progress.style.width = `${percent}%`;

}
progress.addEventListener('click', scrub)
progress.addEventListener('mousemove', scrub)
function scrub(e) {// this is the function which is not getting called at all 
    console.log('sigjeg')
    // const scrubtime = (e.offsetX / progress.offsetWidth) * videoelement.duration;
    // videoelement.currentTime = scrubtime
}
```

```css
body
{
    background-color: blueviolet
}
.videos
{
    width: 50%;
    margin-left:20%;
    margin-right: 20%;
    margin-top:10%;
}
.controlplayer
{
    display:none;
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-right: 20%;
    background-color: ;
}
#volume
{
    width: 36%;
    /* margin-left: 42%;
    margin-right: 40%; */
    margin-top: 0%;
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
}
#playbackspeed
{
    width:36%;
    /* margin-left:25%;
    margin-right:40%;
    margin-top:0; */
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
}
.r
{
     background-color: Transparent;
    border: none;           
    cursor:pointer; 
    width: 9%;
    /* margin-left: 60%;
    margin-right: 20%; */
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Video Player</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="videplayercss.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="videoplayer">
        <video src="yourvideo.mp4" autoplay class="videos"> </video>

    </div>
    <div class="controlplayer">
        <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar  progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="12" aria-valuemin="0"
                aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 25%; margin-bottom:5%;"></div>
        </div>
        <i class="fas fa-play"></i>
        <input type="range" min="0" max="1" value="1" step="0.01" id="volume">
        <input type="range" min="0.1" max="3" value="1" step="0.01" id="playbackspeed">
        <i class="fa fa-angle-double-left backward r">10s</i>
        <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right forward r">25s</i>
    </div>
    <script src="videoplayerjs.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/eb0a94b8cf.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: your progress bar needs a height, `.progress-bar{
    height: 100%;
}` all of your handlers work as expected but the bar is only 1 px high at the moment.

Comment: Sorry for not including the height, in my local machine by default height is coming fine but the addeventlistener is not working that's my problem

Comment: [Added the height to your example, works as expected printing `sigjeg` to the console](https://jsfiddle.net/huspfnga/) if i put the mouse over or click on the progress bar. Please add it and try it and then let us know if you still have an issue.

Comment: I just realised you are targetting the wrong element. You need to target `.progress` not `.progress-bar`. I fixed a different issue for you there where the progress bar wasn't showing (as it only works clicking the progress bar itself not the container)

Comment: [Fixed fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/huspfnga/1/) where I changed your progreess variable to `let progress = document.querySelector('.progress-bar, .progress')` so that it targets the progress bar **and** the progress bar container.

Comment: Thank You @GrahamRitchie , can you add the functionality that Iam looking for and post it as your answer please

Comment: Not a problem, added it as an answer for you. Good luck with the project!

Comment: @GrahamRitchie `document.querySelector('.progress-bar, .progress')` is not targeting both elements, `document.querySelector` returns a single element, the first matching one. Targeted element should be only the progress bar container, not the progress and never both. The parent will receive events from the children.

Comment: Cheers for catching that mistake, corrected my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue OP had was two fold.

First the actual progress bar did not have a height (so could never receive a `click` event or `mousemove` event), this was easily fixed with the addition of `.progress-bar{height: 100%}`.

The second (and the main cause of the issues with the event handler not firing) was that they were targeting the progress bar itself, not the container.

**incorrect - see edit** As the progress bar can be in front of the progress container we need to target both to capture all events.

**incorrect - see edit** By changing the selector to  `let progress = document.querySelector('.progress-bar, .progress')` we can capture events on both easily.

Below is a working example, with comments in the CSS and JS to highlight the changes.

### Edit

As pointed out in a comment by @ErnestoStifano I was sleeping on the job and didn't realise a simple mistake.

You only need target the parent element due to event propagation (and `querySelector` will only capture the first element it finds in the DOM, to target multiple elements you should use `querySelectorAll`), it only worked due to the fact the parent element contained the progress bar. Corrected below.

```js
let videoelement = document.querySelector('.videos')
let pausebutton = document.querySelector('.fas');
let skipbutton = document.querySelector('.forward');
let backbutton = document.querySelector('.backward');
let speed = document.querySelector('#playbackspeed');
let vol = document.querySelector('#volume');
let controls = document.querySelector('.controlplayer')
//let progress = document.querySelector('.progress-bar') ----- changed this to include the container below
let progress = document.querySelector('.progress')
vol.addEventListener('change', setvol)
vol.addEventListener('mousedown', setvol)
function setvol(e) {
    videoelement.volume = vol.value;
}
speed.addEventListener('change', rate)
speed.addEventListener('mousedown', rate)
function rate(e) {
    //  console.dir(speed);
    videoelement.playbackRate = speed.value;
}
pausebutton.addEventListener('click', playing)
videoelement.addEventListener('mouseenter', function () {
    controls.style.display = 'block';
})
videoelement.addEventListener('click', playing)
videoelement.addEventListener('play', updatebutton)
videoelement.addEventListener('pause', updatebutton)
videoelement.addEventListener('timeupdate', handleprogress)
function updatebutton() {
    if (videoelement.paused) {
        pausebutton.classList.remove('fa-pause')
        pausebutton.classList.add('fa-play')
    }
    else {
        pausebutton.classList.remove('fa-play')
        pausebutton.classList.add('fa-pause')
    }
}
function playing(e) {
    console.dir(videoelement)
    if (videoelement.paused) {
        // console.log("pause hai ")
        videoelement.play();
        playing
        videoelement.controls = null;
        videoelement.firstChild.nodeValue = 'Play';
        pausebutton.classList.remove('fa-play')
        pausebutton.classList.add('fa-pause')
    } else {
        //console.log("play ho gya")
        videoelement.pause();
        videoelement.firstChild.nodeValue = 'Pause';
        pausebutton.classList.remove('fa-pause')
        pausebutton.classList.add('fa-play')
    }
    //  this.preventDefault();
}
skipbutton.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    let t = videoelement.currentTime;
    if ((t + 25) < videoelement.duration)
        videoelement.currentTime = t + 25;
    else
        videoelement.currentTime = videoelement.duration;
})
backbutton.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    let t = videoelement.currentTime;
    if ((t - 10) >= 0)
        videoelement.currentTime = t - 10;
    else
        videoelement.currentTime = 0;
})
function handleprogress() {
    let percent = (videoelement.currentTime / videoelement.duration) * 100;
    progress.style.width = `${percent}%`;

}
progress.addEventListener('click', scrub)
progress.addEventListener('mousemove', scrub)
function scrub(e) {// this is the function which is not getting called at all 
    console.log(e.target);
    console.log('sigjeg')
    // const scrubtime = (e.offsetX / progress.offsetWidth) * videoelement.duration;
    // videoelement.currentTime = scrubtime
}
```

```css
body
{
    background-color: blueviolet
}
.videos
{
    width: 50%;
    margin-left:20%;
    margin-right: 20%;
    margin-top:10%;
}
.controlplayer
{
    display:none;
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-right: 20%;
    background-color: ;
}
#volume
{
    width: 36%;
    /* margin-left: 42%;
    margin-right: 40%; */
    margin-top: 0%;
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
}
#playbackspeed
{
    width:36%;
    /* margin-left:25%;
    margin-right:40%;
    margin-top:0; */
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
}
.r
{
    background-color: Transparent;
    border: none;           
    cursor:pointer; 
    width: 9%;
    /* margin-left: 60%;
    margin-right: 20%; */
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
}
/******added a height to the progress bar itself so that it shows***********/
.progress-bar
{     
    height: 100%; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Video Player</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="videplayercss.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="videoplayer">
        <video src="yourvideo.mp4" autoplay class="videos"> </video>

    </div>
    <div class="controlplayer">
        <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar  progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="12" aria-valuemin="0"
                aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 25%; margin-bottom:5%;"></div>
        </div>
        <i class="fas fa-play"></i>
        <input type="range" min="0" max="1" value="1" step="0.01" id="volume">
        <input type="range" min="0.1" max="3" value="1" step="0.01" id="playbackspeed">
        <i class="fa fa-angle-double-left backward r">10s</i>
        <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right forward r">25s</i>
    </div>
    <script src="videoplayerjs.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/eb0a94b8cf.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I've cleaned up your code and found that the event was being targeted on the wrong element (progress bar fill and not progress bar itself).

In addition to another answer I've just saw, there is no need to target both elements (bar and fill) because of how events propagation works (parent elements will receive all events bubbling from nested elements).

```js
const videoElement = document.querySelector('.videos');
const pauseButton = document.querySelector('.fas');
const skipButton = document.querySelector('.forward');
const backButton = document.querySelector('.backward');
const speed = document.querySelector('#playbackSpeed');
const vol = document.querySelector('#volume');
const controls = document.querySelector('.control-player');
const progress = document.querySelector('.progress');

vol.addEventListener('change', setVol);
vol.addEventListener('mousedown', setVol);

function setVol() {
    videoElement.volume = vol.value;
}

speed.addEventListener('change', rate);
speed.addEventListener('mousedown', rate);

function rate() {
    videoElement.playbackRate = speed.value;
}

pauseButton.addEventListener('click', playing);

videoElement.addEventListener('click', playing);
videoElement.addEventListener('play', updateButton);
videoElement.addEventListener('pause', updateButton);
videoElement.addEventListener('timeupdate', handleProgress);
videoElement.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
    controls.style.display = 'block';
});

function updateButton() {
    if (videoElement.paused) {
        pauseButton.classList.remove('fa-pause');
        pauseButton.classList.add('fa-play');
    } else {
        pauseButton.classList.remove('fa-play');
        pauseButton.classList.add('fa-pause');
    }
}

function playing() {
    if (videoElement.paused) {
        videoElement.play();
        videoElement.controls = null;
        videoElement.firstChild.nodeValue = 'Play';
        pauseButton.classList.remove('fa-play');
        pauseButton.classList.add('fa-pause');
    } else {
        videoElement.pause();
        videoElement.firstChild.nodeValue = 'Pause';
        pauseButton.classList.remove('fa-pause');
        pauseButton.classList.add('fa-play');
    }
}

skipButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
    const t = videoElement.currentTime;
    if (t + 25 < videoElement.duration) {
        videoElement.currentTime = t + 25;
    } else {
        videoElement.currentTime = videoElement.duration;
    }
});

backButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
    let t = videoElement.currentTime;
    if (t - 10 >= 0) {
        videoElement.currentTime = t - 10;
    } else {
        videoElement.currentTime = 0;
    }
});

function handleProgress() {
    const percent = (videoElement.currentTime / videoElement.duration) * 100;
    progress.style.width = `${percent}%`;
}

progress.addEventListener('click', scrub);
progress.addEventListener('mousemove', scrub);

function scrub(e) {
    if (e.type === 'click') {
        console.log('click');
    } else {
        console.log('mousemove');
    }
}
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #8a2be2;
}

.videos {
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-right: 20%;
    margin-top: 10%;
}

.control-player {
    display: none;
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-right: 20%;
}

#volume {
    width: 36%;
    margin-top: 0;
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
}

#playbackSpeed {
    width: 36%;
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
}

.r {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 9%;
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
}

.progress-bar {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
    <title>Video Player</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
<div class="video-player">
    <video src="" autoplay class="videos"> </video>
</div>

<div class="control-player">
    <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar  progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="12" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 25%; margin-bottom: 5%;"></div>
    </div>
    <i class="fas fa-play"></i>
    
    <input type="range" min="0" max="1" value="1" step="0.01" id="volume">
    <input type="range" min="0.1" max="3" value="1" step="0.01" id="playbackSpeed">
    
    <i class="fa fa-angle-double-left backward r">10s</i>
    <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right forward r">25s</i>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/eb0a94b8cf.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script></body>

</html>
```

Comment: +1 but to make it a complete answer in its own right you need to add the fact you added a height to the progress bar (I am guessing you copied my snippet not the original one). Thanks for the catch on my mistake.